# Jquery Ajax Buttons

Tags: jquery

Could somebody please tell me why my like button is not working? I attached a like button on my blog and used Ajax to send each like counter to be stored in a mySQL database. But, apparently it is not working. Here are my JQuery functions:

```
$(document).ready(fuction() {


    function likefunction(catch_blog_id) {

    var count = 1;
    var catch_id = catch_blog_id;
    var status = $('#likelink').html(); 
    var vardata = 'count' + count + '&catch_id' + catch_id;


    if (status == "Like") {
    $.ajax({  

        type: "POST",
        url: 'like.php',
        data: vardata,
        success: function() {$('#likelink').html("Unlike");}

    })

    } else {

    $.ajax({  

        type: "POST",
        url: 'unlike.php',
        data: vardata,
        success: function() {$('#likelink').html("Like");}

    })
    }
    }
    })
</script>
```

here is the .php files: one for the like function and the other for the unlike function ==

```
like: 

<?php

include_once('connectserver.php');

$catch_blog_id = $_POST['catch_id'];
$catch_count = $_POST['count'];


$query_blog = mysql_query("SELECT `likes` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

while($get_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_blog)) {


 $likes = $get_rows['likes'];
 $likes = (int)$likes;
 $likes++;

 mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `likes` = '$likes' WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

 }







   ?>


   unlike: 



   <?php

     include_once('connectserver.php');

    $catch_blog_id = $_POST['catch_id'];
       $catch_count = $_POST['count'];


      $query_blog = mysql_query("SELECT `likes` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

     while($get_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_blog)) {


     $likes = $get_rows['likes'];
   $likes = (int)$likes;
    $likes--;

       mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `likes` = '$likes' WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

        }







    ?>
```

here is part of the html file used to store the like button:

echo "
Like Comment";

Comment: Your count is always equal to 1 in your javascript code (in the variable `vardata`).  Also, you need equal signs between your variable and values in the $_POST data.

Comment: that count is redundant. i shud have deleted that part...ignore the count..i set backend sql data to 0 and increments it by bringing it up from a query

Answer (score 0):

It is like vardata is not seen in the server end that why noting seems not to work. Try using

```
vardata = {
           count: count,
           catch_id: catch_id
}


$.post(like.php, vardata, function( res ){
          $('#likelink').html("Unlike");
 });
```

Comment: what is callback and how can i use it? is it similar to the success function that i used?

Comment: @JOSEPHALCATRAZ callback is just the success function so you can use it like function(res){$('#likelink').html("Like");}

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function likefunction(catch_blog_id) {
        var count = 1;
        var catch_id = catch_blog_id;
        var status = $('#likelink').html(); 
        var vardata = 'count=' + count + '&catch_id=' + catch_id;       

        if (status == "Like") {
            $.ajax({            
                type: "POST",
                url: 'like.php',
                data: vardata,
                success: function() {$('#likelink').html("Unlike");}            
            });

        } else {

            $.ajax({            
                type: "POST",
                url: 'unlike.php',
                data: vardata,
                success: function() {$('#likelink').html("Like");}          
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this PHP Code for like.php:

```
<?php
include_once('connectserver.php');

$catch_blog_id = $_POST['catch_id'];

mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

?>
```

And this PHP code for unlike.php:

```
<?php
include_once('connectserver.php');

$catch_blog_id = $_POST['catch_id'];

mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE `id` = '$catch_blog_id'");

?>
```

Comment: To work in this way, datatype of `likes` field in table `posts` should be  `INTEGER (or INT), SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, and BIGINT`.